# D3 with latest leaflet version

Tags: d3.js, leaflet, angular-leaflet-directive

All the sample available for using leaflet with d3 is using leaflet version 0.7.x which was released in 2015.

Why are all modules and examples using so old leaflet version?
**For ex:**

- https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive

  https://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/

  http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535

  http://bl.ocks.org/Sumbera/10463358

When I try to update for ex this http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/9267535 to latest leaflet version it breaks.

Is there any reason why all the example still use so old leaflet version?

Comment: Can anyone please provide a d3+leaflet sample to draw a circles using latest leaflet version

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to solve all the breaking changes.

1) Leaflet no longer uses "viewreset" to watch for zoom changes rather it uses "zoom" to monitor zoomin/zoomout.

2) No more uses map._initPathRoot(); to add svg layer.

Comment: Is there any other changes in addition to the above changes? I replaced map.on('viewreset', update) with map.on('zoom', update)  and commented out map._initPathRoot() still my SVG is not getting rendered though I don't have any error.

Comment: @KarthikPrasad Did you solve the issue?  My tooltips stopped working after moving beyond leaflet 0.7

Comment: @Chris you check this https://github.com/kprasad99/angular-d3-leaflet, however I created this 3 years back not sure how well it will get along now.